Quarkus Multiple Client IDs for same Keycloak Realm
Quarkus backend is currently using quarkus-oidc to authenticate in a keycloak realm with client-id A. Now we want to allow the APIs to be accessed for client-id B as well.  There is no change to the Rest API Urls since, it is basically being accessed by two keycloak clients in the same realm. How would this be implemented?
